# Android crash with permission UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have received a crash with android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS permission in Crashlytics. I don't request this permission in my app because I don't need it. I can't reproduce this issue. The crash happened when the app tried to call query method in ContentResolver.

Maybe someone bumped into this problem and knows reasons or how to fix it. It happened on **Galaxy J5(2016)**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.myapp.App: java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10166 does not have android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS.
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6326)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:223)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10166 does not have android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS.
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
       at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:4240)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:6394)
       at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2380)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1521)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:486)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:445)
       at com.myapp.wrapper.AppSettingWrapper.getDeviceId(AppSettingWrapper.java:103)
       at com.myapp.wrapper.AppSettingWrapper.setNewDeviceId(AppSettingWrapper.java:160)
       at com.myapp.App.onCreate(Mail2WorldApplication.java:70)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1037)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6323)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:223)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

**EDIT:**
Code of getDeviceId method

```
public static String getDeviceId(Context context){
    boolean isNotEnd = true;
    String deviceId = "";
    while (isNotEnd) { // I guess this loop is needed to refetch data, if the app wasn't able to fetch getDeviceId from the first time 
        isNotEnd = false;
        Uri uriDeviceId = AppSettingsContentProvider.DEVICE_ID_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uriDeviceId, null, null, null, null);
        if(cursor != null){
            try {
                if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    deviceId = cursor.getString(0);
                }
            } catch (CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                isNotEnd = true;
            }finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }else{
            isNotEnd = true;
        }
    }
    return deviceId;
}
```

Comment: I suspect the call to `setNewDeviceId()` means you _do_ need `UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS` -- but you won't get that without being a "system" app, which means either building your own ROM or rooting the phone.

Comment: @TripeHound no, setNewDeviceId() it's my method in wrapper. Inside of setNewDeviceId() I call query to my content provider

Comment: Can you show `com.myapp.wrapper.AppSettingWrapper.getDeviceId(AppSettingWrapper.java:103)` ?

Comment: @AxelH sure, I added into EDIT part

Comment: Thanks, please provide a [mcve], I will need `AppSettingsContentProvider.DEVICE_ID_CONTENT_URI` too. I don't see the reason yet ... so if I could reproduce it, it would be nice. NOTE : By reproductible, I mean a short program using the same logic, I know you can't reproduce it but if I have everything, I can investigate more

Comment: @AxelH I guess that AppSettingsContentProvider.DEVICE_ID_CONTENT_URI won't get you more information. I can create simple app where I'll make the same logic as in my project

Comment: Yes they idea of a [mcve] is to be able to reproduce the same process to hope to get the error. It always help in specific question like those

Comment: @AxelH Hello. I've finally created a simple project. You can fetch it here https://github.com/Zo2m4bie/UpdateDeviceStatsErrorResearch , but I cannot provide GcmSenderId from our app. If you have some, you can write it in const SENDER_ID which locates in App class. Thank you

Comment: I've got a similar report from Crashlytics. It's also Samsung (SM-G5520 Android 6.0.1) `Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.****/com.*****Activity}: java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10487 does not have android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS.`

Answer (score -2):

For api greater than 23 you need to add the run time permission.

1) Check the minimum sdk version should be greater than 15.

2) The maximum sdk version should be greater than 23 or 23.

3) You need to call the run time permission every time when you access the external storage or anything else.

4) Please refer this sites for runtime permission http://www.truiton.com/2016/04/obtaining-runtime-permissions-android-marshmallow-6-0/

https://www.sitepoint.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-m-and-n/

http://www.journaldev.com/10409/android-handling-runtime-permissions-example

Comment: Yes, I know about runtime permission. And In question I mentioned that, I don't use this permission in my app

Comment: useless answer and off-topic